# Histogram of different classes of variables in one column

Tags: r, visualization, ggplot2

I have a basic ggplot2 R question. I have a dataframe in which data looks like this:

```
AA 4
AA 6
BB 6
AB 5
BA 4
AA 3
NN 2
AN 6
NN 5
AN 4
NA 3
BB 6
BN 5
NB 1
BN 7
```

The file is of multiple lines. I want to make a histogram using gplot2 that will plot the 9 kinds of variables AA,BB,AB,BA,AN,BN,NN,NB,NA on the x-axis and the sum of it's corresponding values in the next column on the y-axis.

So for example, here the y-values should be

```
AA= 13
BB= 12
AB= 5
BA= 4
NN= 7
AN= 10
NA= 3
BN= 12
NB= 1
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about bioinformatics

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Should I delete the question?

Comment: No, it might help other people. But please search the internet before posting questions. (Also have a look at StackOverflow, many times it has been already asked and answered). Finding solutions to own's problem is a good skill to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a bioinformatics question, but it's quicker to answer than to close.

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
AA 4
AA 6
BB 6
AB 5
BA 4
AA 3
NN 2
AN 6
NN 5
AN 4
NA 3
BB 6
BN 5
NB 1
BN 7", na.strings = "")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Good to know, I don't think that function was around when I started with ggplot2.

Comment: Yes, I think it was added somewhat recently (precisely because `geom_bar` has such a wonky default).

Comment: "This isn't a bioinformatics question, but it's quicker to answer than to close." Nevertheless we can close it.